# How much load can my network handle?

Tags: networking, traffic-management

I have an company network that is not that big. A couple of servers, around 100 pcs and 10 printers.I wonder how much traffic load this network can handle. Is there a way to benchmark how much traffic can my network infrastructure handle? a tool, monitor, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Also, if you're running 10/100, you may want gigabit. Gigabit is generally enough for most applications.

Comment: I believe the question mentioned as duplicate is mostly about for a specific application and not the network overall

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the specs for network components like switches and routers and see how much speed the backplanes can handle. That's a good starting point. It's not quite as simple as adding up all the traffic number of connections and the type of traffic and affect the performance of network components.

You can use a tool like iperf http://iperf.fr to measure traffic flows between two machines which will tell you the maximum speed you can get between two machines connected to the network. You could try running such flows between multiple sets of machines. That will give you some idea of performance, but will certainly not be a complete or exhaustive benchmarking effort. Just one tool you could use amongst many.